# How to link tt_news H1 title to the news itself?

Tags: typo3, tt-news

For the SEO reason, I have to link the news title in single view to the news itself. When I try this by `###LINK_ITEM###` marker it links to the (return-page) I've chosen in flexforms to return.

How should I link that title to the page itself, it also can be used as PERMALINK the other systems like wordpress have.

Comment: How does this improve the seo of the page? From a usability point of view, it is not very helpful, so I doubt it will improve any seo ranking. Do you have a reference for this behavior?

Comment: Experimentally I have to do this... Because when I link (Related News) under a tt_news page, google index that related links much more faster than the news itself. I thought if I link the title itself it may help SEO. I've seen many sites that link the title and I have to do this for test.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend tt_news with new marker.

- create the extension with the kickstarter or just create empty one (extend tt_news table if
  necessary)
- create hook-objects and register for the hook "extraItemMarkerProcessor"
- create the marker and content within that hook and assign value of current url $url=t3lib_div::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_URL');